# is it possible to display GLib Icon on Clutter Image?

Tags: glib, vala, clutter

I'm currently working on a file-manager with vala and clutter and i was wondering is it possible to display GLib.Icon ( Fileinfo.get_icon() ) in Clutter.Image instead of just displaying one folder icon from it's location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the icon is a `GLib.LoadableIcon` you should be able to use `GLib.LoadableIcon.load` to get a `GLib.InputStream`, then us that to create a `Gdk.Pixbuf` with `Gdk.Pixbuf.from_stream`.  From there use `Clutter.Image.set_data` to copy the data into the Clutter.Image.

To test whether the icon is a `GLib.LoadableIcon`, just do something like `GLib.LoadableIcon loadable_icon = icon as GLib.LoadableIcon; if (loadable_icon != null) { ... }`